# YouTube Analytics API Report.Query by Day with Timezone

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I know, there is another Topic here with a similar Question, but the main Question has not been answered yet (as far as I understand).
Given, that the YouTube Analytics API is returning everything in "Pacific time zone", and I query the Data for "one Day" (via StartDate/EndDate) - the returned Data may not really make sense to me, if I need them in UTC. If the ViewCount for example comes as "800 Views" on 2017-12-24, this is 2017-12-24 in that Timezone, not the 2017-12-24 in a European Timezone (or at least UTC). SO basically, this Information is not helpfull at all to get the Amount of Views per Day from a User in a different Timezone.
How can this be corrected? Is there a Way to add a Timezone (I didnt find one), or to add a Starting/End HOUR, to get really a Day-Bucketed Collection in UTC?

Thanks,
Christoph